# Does reputation from accepted edits count towards the daily rep cap

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

In the FAQ for the new Fitness and Nutrition site which is in closed beta it says;

> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per
>   user per day, and you can earn a
>   maximum of 200 reputation per day
>   (although accepted answers and bounty
>   awards are immune to this limit).
>   Please note that votes for posts
>   marked "community wiki" do not
>   generate reputation.
>
> The other way to gain reputation is by
>   suggesting edits to existing posts as
>   a new registered user. Each edit will
>   be peer reviewed, and if it is
>   accepted, you will earn +2 reputation.
>   You can only earn a maximum of +1000
>   total reputation through suggested
>   edits, however.

I want to check if edits also count towards the daily rep cap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, edits also count towards daily rep.